# Python script called from UFT(VB Script) is not working as expected

Tags: python, image, hp-uft

I have python script to split the capture.png(image) file into parts. Python script works fine when i run it individually and images are created correctly after splitting.
Am calling this python script from UFT code to do splitting job, but when it is called from UFT script runs and does nothing.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Below is the python code to split the image. I have developed a lib file (ImageExtractorTrial) to do my job. This will split my image and copy the splitted images in the same folder.

```
import ImageExtractorTrial
import cv2
from ImageExtractorTrial import pre_requisites_extractor
PreRequisites = pre_requisites_extractor().auto_extraction("Capture.png")
for req in PreRequisites:    
    cv2.imshow(req[1], cv2.imread(req[0]))
    print("Image: %s"%req[0])
    print("Status: %s"%req[1])
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Below is the UFT code am using to call python script.

```
Set pyShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
pySplitimage = "python ""C:\Users\a291068\Desktop\Python\Python\codes\Splitimages.py"""
Set pyOperation = pyShell.Exec(pySplitimage)
Set pyResult = pyOperation.StdOut
wait(1)
pyReturn = pyResult.ReadAll
```

My python code works perfectly when run individually but does nothing when triggered from UFT.Please help me.

[image: This is the image am trying to split in python into three parts]

Comment: And what does this have to do with vb.net?

Comment: Yes i have all other code in vb.net

Comment: I have another python script to read the color of the image which is also triggered from VB.net code and that is working fine. Only issue with this code

Comment: Try `SystemUtil.Run "python", "C:\Users\a291068\Desktop\Python\Python\codes\Splitimages.py"`